# Reading from a Database throws exception on second attempt?

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb

I've got an application that, when a button is clicked, reads an access database for products and lists them in a listbox and dataGridView. The connection command text is `northwind_command.CommandText = "SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE UnitPrice > (@price_greater_than)";`

On the first click the program will work, but when the button is clicked a second time an exception is thrown. As this thrown exception causes the data reader to "crash", the third click will work as if it was the first. The fourth click will throw the same exception. If I had to guess, I'd say that the the datareader isn't closing properly, but it should be. Here is the code for that part of the program:

```
northwind_connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='U:\Programming\C#\Week 13\Exercises\ExerciseA1\bin\northwind.mdb';Persist Security Info=True";
        northwind_command.Connection = northwind_connection; // connects the command to the connection.
        northwind_command.CommandText = "SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE UnitPrice > (@price_greater_than)"; // sets the query used by this command.
        northwind_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_greater_than", price_greater_than);

        try
        {
            northwind_connection.Open(); // opens the connection.
            northwind_reader = northwind_command.ExecuteReader(); // reads the data from the connection while executing the command.

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ProductName", "Product Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", "Product Price");
            while (northwind_reader.Read())
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(northwind_reader["ProductName"], northwind_reader["UnitPrice"]);
                listBox1.Items.Add(northwind_reader["ProductName"] + "\t" + northwind_reader["UnitPrice"]);
            }
        }catch(Exception mistake)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mistake.ToString());
        }
        northwind_connection.Close();
```

EDIT: I've solved the issue with some help, but would like to figure out why it was happening in the first place. The offending line was `northwind_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_greater_than", price_greater_than);`. The line above that one was modified to: `northwind_command.CommandText = "SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE UnitPrice > " + price_greater_than;` and the program now works correctly.

That method was causing the exception to be thrown, which can be seen below: [image]

I checked the exception message and line 50 contains this code: `northwind_reader = northwind_command.ExecuteReader();`, which confirms that the `AddwithValue` method was causing the error.

Comment: show us the exception/error message

Comment: @Irfan if he puts `Close()` after `while(){...}`, and an exception is thrown in that loop or anywhere in the `try{}` clause, the connection would never get closed. When he creates the connection, it should be done in a `using`, or if he does not want to do that, it should be in a `finally{}` clause.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that something is not getting disposed of properly. Try modifying your code to use `using` statements:

```
using(var northwindConnection = new OleDbConnection())
{
    //Set your connection info

    using(var northwindCommand = northwindConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        //Set your command info

        try
        {
            // Open your connection and any other things 
            // needed before executing your reader
            using(var reader = northwindCommand.ExecuteReader()){
                //Do what you need with your reader
            }
        }
        catch(Exception mistake)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mistake.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When a class implements `IDisposable`, you really should wrap that in a `using` statement. Doing so will make sure that all resources are properly disposed. In the case of database connections, this will make sure that your connection is closed, so no need to call `myConn.Close()`.

Another things that might be causing issues is that you are adding columns to `dataGridView1` every time the button is clicked.

Edit:
Since you found the problem is with `AddWithValue`, let me add this:

In past experience, I have had issues using the `@paramName` syntax with `OleDbCommand`. Try using `?paramNam` syntax instead. I have also had issues if the name is to long, so try shortening it.

You should use `Paramaters.Add(string, OleDbType).Value = value` instead of `Paramaters.AddWithValue(string, value)`. The reason being is that `AddWithValue` has to interpret the type of the column, and it can sometimes get it wrong.

Comment: I've checked that and the dataGridView columns are fine. It's without a doubt being caused by the AddWithValue method, as reworking that section to avoid using that method has fixed the issue.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich see my edits. They might not solve your issues, but they are some better coding practices.

Answer (score 1):

Add `northwind_reader.Close()` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: If he puts `Close()` after `while(){...}`, and an exception is thrown in that loop or anywhere in the `try{}` clause, the connection would never get closed. When he creates the connection, it should be done in a `using`, or if he does not want to do that, it should be in a `finally{}` clause.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. I prefer to do by `using`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close reader before use it again.

example:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
string value = reader.GetValue(0).tostring();
}
reader.Close();
```

in your case is northwind_command.close()